# BusterJS freezes when a lib is included

Tags: javascript, web-testing, buster.js

I have the following setup:

buster.js:

```
var config = module.exports;

config["web-module"] = {
    autoRun: true,
    environment: "browser",
    rootPath: ".",
    libs: [
        //"app/webroot/src/lib/underscore.js"
    ],
    sources: [

    ],
    tests: [
        "buster_simpletest.js"
    ]
};
```

buster_simpletest.js:

```
buster.testCase("My thing", {

    "states the obvious": function () {
        console.log("TEST");
        assert(true);
    }

});
```

This setup runs fine and I get the expected console output:

```
Chrome 24.0.1312.57, Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7:

Passed: Chrome 24.0.1312.57, Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 My thing states the obvious
    [LOG] TEST

1 test case, 1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 timeouts.
Finished in 0.004s
```

However, it doesn't as soon as I include any of the libs (I tried underscore.js, jQuery and several others.)

I don't get a single line of console output. No error, no nothing. It simply freezes there.

I also tried to disable `autoRun` and include a `run.js` which calls `buster.run();`, but the result was the same.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:**

Ok I tested some more and it seems to have problems with the folder depth. Here is my folder structure:

```
root
 - buster.js
 - buster_simpletest.js
 - underscore.js
 - a
   - underscore.js
   - b
     - underscore.js
```

And here's my testing result:

```
libs: [
    //"underscore.js"      // works
    //"a/underscore.js"    // works
    //"a/b/underscore.js"  // freezes
    //"a/b/xunderscore.js" // Error: "Failed loading configuration: "a/b/xunderscore.js" matched no files or resources"
]
```

As you can see it freezes as soon as I have depth of 2 folders. Although it is able to find the file, as I get an error if I try to include an invalid file.

**Edit 2:**

Seems to be a bug with windows only. The same setup works fine on our linux machine. 
I guess we have to wait for proper windows support.